# React: Adding an object to an array in state through input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I want to read two text field values and use a button to reset my state. Here's my code:

```
this.state = {

  items: [{
    name: 'Cola',
    price: 1.20
  }, {
    name: 'Stuff',
    price: 0.50
  }, {
    name: 'Beer',
    price: 0
  }
]
};


handle = (name, price) => {
    this.addProductToBasket(name, price);
  }

addProductToBasket = (name, price) => {

    var newArray = this.state.items.slice();

    var itemToBeAdded = {
      name : name,
      price : price
    }; 

    newArray.push(itemToBeAdded);
    console.log(newArray)

    this.setState( {items:newArray} )

}


<form onSubmit={ () => this.handle(this.state.items.name, this.state.items.price)}>
  <input type="text" name='name' value={this.state.items.name}/>
  <input type="text" name='price' value={this.state.items.price}/>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

I tested

> addProductToBasket

and it works! I debugged the code in Chrome and I just get *undefined* for *name* and *price*.

Comment: Where is `this.state.name` and `this.state.price`?

Comment: can you put a console log inside handle function to check whether the price and name values are coming ?

Comment: Sorry. I meant this.state.items.name and this.state.items.price.

EDIT:

I changed *this.state.name* and *this.state.price* to *this.state.items.name* and *this.state.items.price*.

Comment: `this.state.items.price` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Sameera - They're just undefined.

Comment: @Claim0013 I guess the main challenge would be you're storing array of objects in items and trying to getting data in `render` like this is just a simple object ie `value={this.state.items.name}`. I guess it should have some indexes as well like `value={this.state.items[0].name}` for reference

Comment: @Andy Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vineet I'm quite confused at how I should attempt solving this problem since I just started a few days ago with react and the syntax is still difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your state to include `name` and `price`:

```
this.state = {
  name: '',
  price: '',
  items: [...]
}
```

You want to add a new function that handles changes in your input fields. Call it `handleInput`. It takes the event, grabs the name of the input, and sets the appropriate state value of that key.

```
handleInput(e) {
  let { name, value } = e.target;
  if (name === 'price') value = +value;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}
```

Here's the corresponding JSX:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.name} />
 <input type="text" name="price" onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.price} />
```

And **[here's a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rgwL5zcj/18/)**. Look at the console for the changes to `this.state`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, the values are not undefined anymore. Could you explain me this syntax though *this.setState({ [name]: value });*

The page is refreshing every time I add something new to the list.

Comment: Okay nevermind, I could just add *e.preventDefault();* to stop it from refreshing.

Comment: Yes. It uses the _value_ of `name` (the name of your input element) as the key when it sets the new state. If you don't use the square notation it will just set `this.state.name` instead.

Comment: Oh okay, now I get it. I was also confused about `handleInput(e)` since I thought it handles both inputs but then it hit me.

Gonna look at something else than form since, `e.preventDefault()` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed to the handle function are incorrect. They are currently referring to the array of items in state, but it should be referring to the input field values.

Create something like `this.state.input.name` and `this.state.input.price`. These would have to be set by text field onChange handlers.

Answer (score 0):

As @sketchedin pointed out, the parameters passed are not the value entered by user itself but instead are bound to the state object.

In order to pass the parameters you either have to call an `onChange()` function but instead if you want to call it from the handle function of form you should make sure that you capture the current input values(i.e. the params passed should be bound to the input and not the state object).

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const data = new FormData(form);

  const name = form.elements[name];
  const price = form.elements[price];

  this.addProductToBasket(name, price);
}
```

What we are doing in the above lines is that we are using DOM api's form element and fetching the correct input values instead of using REACT to manipulate the forms.